# How to bypass the Elevated prompt error during silent installation

Tags: windows, batch-file, anaconda

I am trying to download and silently install `Anaconda` on user's computer by using a batch file. The command that is used in my batch files is according to the original documentation of Anaconda. However, every time I run this batch of code, it gives me an error that says:

> Installation for all users requires an elevated prompt.

This however only happens when I set the installation type to `AllUsers`. If I set the installation type to `JustMe`, it will be able to download and install Anaconda.

```
curl "https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-4.3.0.1-Windows-x86.exe" -o "prerequisites\\Anaconda2-4.3.0.1-Windows-x86.exe"
%cd%\prerequisites\Anaconda2-4.3.0.1-Windows-x86.exe /InstallationType=AllUsers /RegisterPython=1 /S /D=C:\Anaconda
```

Unfortunately, I need to find a way to set the installation type to `AllUsers`. I had also tried running the batch file using administrator mode but to no avail. Can anyone tell me what I am missing out? I've been on this for days and still could not find the correct solution to this.

Comment: You can't install as AllUsers without admin privileges. There is no way to bypass that if UAC is enabled, period. If you could just selectively bypass it to do whatever you wanted, that would make UAC pretty useless. If you want your code to do things that require elevation, you need to run elevated. The error message is very clear and very specific; it answers this question without your having to ask it. **Installation for all users requires an elevated prompt**. It's hard to understand what part of that is not clear. It doesn't say *unless you don't want it to do so*.

Comment: May I know what exactly is running it elevated?

Comment: Running as an administrator. Normal users don't have access to other user's folders; only an administrator can do so, which is why an administrator account is required to install for AllUsers.